# Is there a way to optimize a query when retrieving multiple records based on a foreign key?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query:

```
delete from tbl_table
where user = '123'
```

accessing an example tbl_table:

```
id user phonenumber
1 123 (408)555-5555
2 123 (415)555-5555
3 123 (913)555-5555
```

when I run a delete, it takes 7000+ ms which seems excessive. This is on a 400k record table.

Wondering how I could structure the db or the query in order to potentially takes less time to execute.

Comment: You might consider "soft-deleting" instead only problem might/will be the EU GDPR compliance even if your company is not located within EU, as long as you're dealing with EU businesses’, residents’, or citizens’ data, you will have to comply with the GDPR..  You could "soft-delete" first and use a cronjob/MySQL event in the night to "hard delete"

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit complicated.  The performance of a delete is affected by many things:

- How long does it take to find the rows to be deleted?
- How many rows are being deleted?
- What indexes built on the table also need to be modified?
- What else is happening on the system?
- What delete triggers are defined on the table?

That makes it hard to answer to the question.  The first two can be addressed.  For the first, an index helps:

```
create index idx_tbl_table_user on tbl_table(user);
```

To use this index, be sure that you have the right types.  Numeric ids are usually stored as numbers and not strings -- and type conversions can sometimes impede the use of indexes.  So if `user` is a number, you want to write:

```
where use = 123
```

The second problem of deleting "too many" rows can be handled in a more arduous fashion.  You can create a temporary table with the data you want to keep, truncate the original table, and re-insert the values.  Alas, I doubt you could finish this in 7 seconds, so that is not an option.

As for the other three, you need further investigation into your system and tables if these are the cause of the delay.  Of course, if system load is the issue, then running the query at a quieter time will speed the query.

Comment: "You can create a temporary table with the data you want to keep, truncate the original table" That would most likely will create a temporary disk based table which will be slow... Mounting MySQL's tempdir on a ramdisk will speed this up

Answer (score 0):

A best possible approach would be

- Create an index on user column.
- make your operation
- delete your index (If it is a one-time operation)

```
CREATE INDEX idx_tbl_user ON tbl_table (user); 
DELETE FROM tbl_table WHERE user = '123'; 
DROP INDEX idx_tbl_user;
```

Comment: Why would I want to delete the index afterwards? is there a performance hit keeping the index?

Comment: yes, of course it does. Keeping index has both negative and positive sides. most important cons I can think of is Disk Storage Requirements, Insert Operation overheads (takes more time), Index maintenance,  So, there is always debate about creating indices. But in general, if you are going to use user field regularly, then you need it